# rewrite error when one value is empty

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have this line here;

```
RewriteRule ^news/(.*)/(.*)/$ ./news.php?type=$1&number=$2 [L]
```

But when one of the 2 values is empty it shows an error that the page is not found. As example I did;
localhost/news/dgfgh

Is there a way to fix this?

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} "/admin/"
# Remove .php extension
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ /[^?\s]+\.php
RewriteRule (.*)\.php$ /$1/ [L,R=301]


RewriteRule ^news/(.*)/(.*)/$ ./news.php?type=$1&number=$2 [L]


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(.+)/$
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%1.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ $1.php [L]


# Force trailing slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule .*[^/]$ $0/ [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Regular Expression in your rewrite rule does not match localhost/news/dgfgh

The rewrite rule is looking for news followed by exactly two groups, followed by a trailing slash.  To do what you want, you need two rules.

```
RewriteRule ^news/(.*)/(.*)/?$ ./news.php?type=$1&number=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^news/(.*)/?$ ./news.php?type=$1 [L]
```

The first one is yours with a simple `?` before the trailing slash to indicate that the trailing slash is options.  The second one is for the case when you don't have the number in the url as in your example